# What exactly determines the encounter rates of different Pokémon in White Forest?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I have four named characters in my White Forest: Britney, Collin, Gene and Vincent. [According to Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/White_Forest), this means that in patches of long grass I should encounter Hoppip, Abra, Aron and Magby, which has proven to be the case. However, I should also (by Bulbapedia's reckoning) see Surskit, Lotad and Corphish while Surfing.

I've had about 30 encounters Surfing so far, and most of them were Surskit, with a handful being Lotad. I haven't yet run into Corphish. The Bulbapedia page seems to suggest that each of these Pokémon should appear equally frequently, but my experience (while I haven't gone through the whole song and dance of a statistical test) doesn't seem to bear that out. Even if you interpret it to mean that Surskit should appear twice as often as the other two (since his presence is due to both Britney and Gene), it still doesn't seem to be consistent with the results I get.

In the case of tall grass encounters, too, it seemed to me that I saw rather more Hoppip and Aron than I saw Abra and Magby. In both tall grass and Surfing encounters, it doesn't seem to me that each of the possible Pokémon is equally likely. What exactly decides how frequently each Pokémon appears?

Comment: I had an answer prepped, but I went to double-check my source and it appears they backpedaled it. Regardless, it appeared from there that each Pokémon actually has a fixed encounter rate, with Corphish being a much lower one than the other surfing entities when they're in the equation. Not sure on the exact mechanics. So until there's an answer, keep surfing, and you'll eventually find a Corphish like I did! Enjoy the forest that's so different from the freewheeling life back in Black City. ♪